# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined Error in ion search bar?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to implement ion search bar in the following way

My HTML page is

```
 <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getFilteredItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
   <button ion-item *ngFor="let patient of surveyPatients | async" (click)="showPatientData(patient)">{{patient.name}} - {{patient.age}} - {{patient.idCardNumber}}</button>
```

Corresponding ts file,

```
 surveyPatients:any;
getFilteredItems(ev: any) {
    this.initializeSurveyPatients();

    let val = ev.target.value;
    alert(val);
    console.log(this.surveyPatients.length);
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.surveyPatients = this.surveyPatients.filter((item) => {
        //alert(item.name);
        return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }


initializeSurveyPatients() {

        this.surveyPatients = this.afoDatabase.list('/SurveyPatients',
      {
        query:{
              orderByChild: 'district',
              equalTo: 'Nalgonda '
            }
      }

      );


  }
```

When I see **alert(val)** I am getting the what ever the input that is entered in the search box. But when I try **console.log(this.surveyPatients.length);** I am getting undefined.
That is the reason why I am getting **Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined** Error.

In the constructor I am running  **this.initializeSurveyPatients();** Hence I am able to see the data in the front end on page load.

Why I am not able to read the collection this.surveyPatients inside the **getFilteredItems** method?

***Updated Code***

```
    initializeSurveyPatients() {

            this.afoDatabase.list('/SurveyPatients',
          {
            query:{
                  orderByChild: 'district',
                  equalTo: 'Nalgonda '
                }
          }

          ).subscribe(snap => {

          this.surveyPatients = snap;

        });
 getFilteredItems(ev: any) {

    //this.initializeItems();
    this.initializeSurveyPatients();

    let val = ev.target.value;
    console.log(this.surveyPatients.length);

    if (val && val.trim() != '' ) {

      this.surveyPatients = this.surveyPatients.filter((item) => {
               return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
       console.log(this.surveyPatients.length);
        }
      }


      }
```

Corresponding html code

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let patient of surveyPatients" (click)="showPatientData(patient)">{{patient.name}} - {{patient.age}}
- {{patient.idCardNumber}}</button>
```

Note: I removed async filter

In this case, I am able to get correct values for **console.log(this.surveyPatients.length);** before filter and after filter as expected, inside **getFilteredItems** method. Which confirms us the filter is working.

The only issue is values In the UI are not updating after the filter.

Comment: Probably because `initializeSurveyPatients` is async. `this.surveyPatients` is not yet defined when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Since that is `observable` you need to `subscribe` it to return a value.

**Note:** Refactor the `code` as you wish.This is just a concept.

```
this.afoDatabase.list('/SurveyPatients',
      {
        query:{
              orderByChild: 'district',
              equalTo: 'Nalgonda '
          } }
      ).subscribe(snap => {

      this.surveyPatients = snap;//here

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try this, I am able to read the item.name property but filter is not working. Also I have to remove async pipe in the front end code. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you show your latest `code`? Put that on the separate section on your question above.

Comment: Can you see this article: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Actually  I am getting expected value for  item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) also. The only thing that I did not understand is why that filter is not working. Is it mandatory to have data provider?

Comment: What did you mean by `data provider` here?

Comment: In the link you have shared, they have used separate data service to manage/filter data.

Comment: Yes, That is good coding practice to maintainable code. We need to follow that.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for getting this error could be that item.name is undefined at the time you try to perform this function.

Try to use some protection like:

`if item.name.type === 'string'`

You can also try to use the Elvis operator:

`item.name?.toLowerCase()`